# Why are the calculated variable not being accepted by the fortran subroutine and functions?

Tags: function, fortran, subroutine, abaqus

In a FORTRAN UMAT subroutine, I am calling for the subroutine **SRT** using

```
     CALL STRT (STATEV(N), STATEV(N), 
 2                    STATEV(N), NIP(N), FIP(N), DSP(N), 
 3                    POP(65), de_log, T_st)
```

---

In the main UMAT subroutine, I am calculating the values for **de_log** and **T_st**. However, I am facing error when trying to include the newly calculated variables into the subroutine ***STRT*** and Functions ***F*** and ***DX***. These functions are not taking the values of de_log and T_st being calculated in the main subroutine. **I can't figure out why the values of de_log and T_st not being seen by the functions.**

```
      SUBROUTINE STRT (GMA, TLP, GIP, NIP, FIP, 
     2                       DSP, POP, de_log, T_st)
C
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      EXTERNAL F, DFDX
      DIMENSION GMA(N), TLP(N), GIP(N), 
     2          FIP(N), DSP(N), POP(8)
        

      DO I=1,N
         X=TLP(I)/GIP(I)
         FIP(I)=F(X,POP)
         DSP(I)=DX(X,POP)
      END DO

      RETURN
      END



           REAL*8 FUNCTION F(X, POP)

              IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
           DIMENSION POP(8)
           TERM1= (POP(3)*de_log)
           TERM2= (T_st**POP(4))
           F=POP(2)*(ABS(X))**POP(1)*DSIGN(1.D0,X)
           F= F*TERM1*TERM2 

           RETURN
           END
           REAL*8 FUNCTION DX(X, POP)

           IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
           DIMENSION POP(8)
           TERM1= (POP(3)*de_log)
           TERM2= (T_st**POP(4))
           DX=POP(1)*POP(2)*(ABS(X))**(POP(1)-1.)
           DX= DFDX*TERM1*TERM2
           
           RETURN
           END
```

Comment: Why do you think the value for de_log should be seen in these functions? You haven't passed it as an argument or similar, so as written it is simply a local variable. And please tell me this isn't new code ...

Comment: @IanBush The main code is not new. I have modified the original code to calculate de_log and T_st in the main subroutine. I want the Function F and DX  to use the value of de_log and T_st in the equation. I tried passing the values as        FIP(I)=F(X,POP, de_log, T_st)
         DSP(I)=DX(X,POP, de_log, T_st) but to no avail. How to pass these as an argument?

Comment: Like you pass any other argument in Fortran, via an actual argument when you invoke the function (as you have) AND a dummy argument in the function itself (which you don't). I'm sorry but I have to say this is very basic Fortran - if you don't understand this a course or studying a book would be very worthwhile.

Comment: If this is new code, it is really bad. Forget the implicit statement. Use `implicit none` only. It is **very** important. And read some tutorial about Fortran 95 or even more modern Fortran. Your code looks like it is from 1960s or 1970s.

Answer (score 0):

One procedure cannot "see" the variables inside of another procedure. Having passed those arguments to the `strt` subroutine does not make them available inside the `f` and `dx` functions. You must also pass them as arguments to those functions. Your code then becomes:

```
      SUBROUTINE STRT (GMA, TLP, GIP, NIP, FIP, 
     2                       DSP, POP, de_log, T_st)
C
      IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
      EXTERNAL F, DFDX
      DIMENSION GMA(N), TLP(N), GIP(N), 
     2          FIP(N), DSP(N), POP(8)
        

      DO I=1,N
         X=TLP(I)/GIP(I)
         FIP(I)=F(X,POP,de_log,T_st)
         DSP(I)=DX(X,POP,de_log,T_st)
      END DO

      RETURN
      END



           REAL*8 FUNCTION F(X, POP,de_log,T_st)

              IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
           DIMENSION POP(8)
           TERM1= (POP(3)*de_log)
           TERM2= (T_st**POP(4))
           F=POP(2)*(ABS(X))**POP(1)*DSIGN(1.D0,X)
           F= F*TERM1*TERM2 

           RETURN
           END
           REAL*8 FUNCTION DX(X, POP,de_log,T_st)

           IMPLICIT REAL*8 (A-H,O-Z)
           DIMENSION POP(8)
           TERM1= (POP(3)*de_log)
           TERM2= (T_st**POP(4))
           DX=POP(1)*POP(2)*(ABS(X))**(POP(1)-1.)
           DX= DFDX*TERM1*TERM2
           
           RETURN
           END
```